# Publish WebService with different bin folder

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, dll, libraries, bin-folder

I created a WebService in Visual-Studio. When right-clicking -> publish, I can choose target folder. After that, when finally hitting publish again, he creates 3 files within that folder:

global.asax
web.config
bin-folder

In this bin folder, he puts all the libraries needed.

As I have another program installed in a different folder, and which needs the same libraries (so they are all already there), now every library is double.

Can I change this auto created bin folder of the webservice somehow? So that he uses the library folder / the .dlls of the other program and does not create every .dll again?

Would be very thankful for every help / explanation.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

No answer at all yet? :(

/push